# please help me in this onclick function for button in js

Tags: javascript, html, input

I wrote this code to replace the element in div:"change" with the input given in textbox:"use10" when the button:"insert" is clicked.But when i click nothing
is happening please help.Here is my code:

```
<div id="change">
    <?php 
    echo $r9['fname'];
    echo "&nbsp;";
    echo $r9['lname'];
    echo "&nbsp;"; 
    ?>
</div>

<div id="dialog" title="Change Details"> 
    <form method="POST" name="changename">
        <input type="text"  id="use10" name="use10" placeholder="First Name">
        <input type="text"  id="use20"  name="use20" placeholder="Last Name">
        <button type="button" type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" class="btn btn-success">Change</button>
        <script>
            document.getElementById("insert").onclick=function(){
            var fn=getElememtById("use10").value;
            document.getElementById("change").innerHTML=fn;}
        </script>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: there is no element with id "change" in your code

Comment: "change" element is not here

Comment: Fixing your html would be a good place to start.

Comment: <div id="change"><?php echo $r9['fname']; ?><?php echo "&nbsp;";echo $r9['lname'];echo "&nbsp;";
      ?></div>

Comment: i edited 2 times in the code area but it is not showing there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/74Lmwcmt/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {  

    document.getElementById("insert").onclick=function(){
     var fn=document.getElementById("use10").value; // you forget to write "document." over here
     document.getElementById("change").innerHTML=fn; // give id of div
    }

});
```

OR

```
window.onload = function() { 

 document.getElementById("insert").onclick=function(){
         var fn=document.getElementById("use10").value; // you forget to write "document." over here
         document.getElementById("change").innerHTML=fn; // give id of div
        }
};
```

Comment: document.getElementById("change").innerHTML="test";

Comment: test is displayed but when input is taken then no response

Comment: I mean to say write your code inside document.ready...I have updated answer above try that

Comment: <script>$( document ).ready(function() {

    document.getElementById("insert").onclick=function(){
     var fn=document.getElementById("use10").value; // you forget to write "document." over here
     document.getElementById("change").innerHTML=fn; // give id of div
    }

});</script>

Comment: i am inserting string in the testbox use10

Comment: do you want to try it in jquery?

Answer (score 0):

I have just used your code and changed it a bit. Check out if this is what you are looking for.

```
<div id="change" title="Change Details">
 <p> <form method="POST" name="changename"><input type="text"  id="use10"
 name="use10" 
 placeholder="First Name"> </p>
 <p> <input type="text"  id="use20"  name="use20"
 placeholder="Last Name"> </p>
 <button type="button" type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" class="btn
 btn-success">Change</button><script>
 document.getElementById("insert").onclick=function(){
 var fn=document.getElementById("use10").value;
 document.getElementById("change").innerHTML=fn;}</script>
 </form>
 </div>
```